# Is it possible to filter the sources in the bibliography (Microsoft Word) by their Type of Source (book, magazine, etc)?

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I am using Microsoft Word 2019 to write a thesis with 100s of references. I was asked to filter the bibliography by Books, Magazines, and Other sources.
Is there any way that I can filter the bibliography by the Type of Source (e.g. Book), or for that matter, is there any alternative method?
I am using APA Sixth Edition. I believe than changing the file (APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl) would help to solve the requirement. In detail the following part:

```
-<b:SortingString>


-<xsl:variable name="author0">


-<xsl:for-each select="./b:Author/*[local-name()=$MostImportantAuthorLocalName]">

<xsl:call-template name="formatPersonsAuthor"/>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:variable>


-<xsl:variable name="author">


-<xsl:choose>


-<xsl:when test="string-length(./b:Author/*[local-name()=$MostImportantAuthorLocalName]/b:Corporate) > 0">

<xsl:value-of select="./b:Author/*[local-name()=$MostImportantAuthorLocalName]/b:Corporate"/>

</xsl:when>


-<xsl:when test="string-length($author0) > 0">

<xsl:value-of select="$author0"/>

</xsl:when>

</xsl:choose>

</xsl:variable>


-<xsl:variable name="title">


-<xsl:choose>


-<xsl:when test="b:SourceType = 'Patent'">


-<xsl:if test="string-length(b:CountryRegion) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:CountryRegion"/>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="string-length(b:PatentNumber) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:PatentNumber"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:when>


-<xsl:when test="string-length(b:Title) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:Title"/>

</xsl:when>

</xsl:choose>

</xsl:variable>


-<xsl:if test="b:SourceType = 'Case'">


-<xsl:if test="string-length($title) > 0">

<xsl:value-of select="$title"/>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="string-length(b:Year) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:Year"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="b:SourceType != 'Case'">


-<xsl:if test="string-length($author) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="$author"/>


-<xsl:if test="string-length(b:Year) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:Year"/>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="string-length($title) > 0">

<xsl:value-of select="$title"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="string-length($author) = 0">


-<xsl:if test="string-length($title) > 0">

<xsl:value-of select="$title"/>

</xsl:if>


-<xsl:if test="string-length(b:Year) > 0">

<xsl:text> </xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="b:Year"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</b:SortingString>
```

what do you believe?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you were given the sources in XML format? why do you use Word for this task?

Comment: Thank you,
You were given the sources in XML format? Yes, I have the file (Sources.xml)
Why do you use Word for this task? The entire work must be presented in this format

Comment: It might be feasible, but the problem with changing the .xsl is that it will only affect the behaviour of Word on *your machine*. Perhaps better to think about "filterting" as a process that *removes* sources that do not match your filter.

Comment: Thank you yokki, “It might be feasible, but the problem with changing the .xsl is that it will only affect the behaviour of Word on your machine.” It would be fine. The document is being written only in one machine. Do you know how the .xsl should be modified?

Answer (score 0):

This Answer shows how it may be possible to do this kind of filtering by altering the .xsl.

I am not completely convinced that this will work if you have multiple references to the same source, but...

The best place to do the filtering seems to me to be in this Template, which populates a copy of the Bibliography data that the .xsl uses from then on. It's about 2/3 of the way down the code.

```
<xsl:template name="populateMain">
```

You would replace the following line

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*[$Type]/b:Source">
```

with this

```
<xsl:variable name="Filtered">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Type='b:Bibliography'">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*[$Type]/b:Source[b:SourceType='Film' or b:SourceType='Book']">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*[$Type]/b:Source">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($Filtered)/b:Source">
```

but then edit this line to do the filtering:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="/*[$Type]/b:Source[b:SourceType='Film' or b:SourceType='Book']">
```

(Unfortunately you may have to get to grips with XPath's syntax details to get that right.)

You can keep your old code in comments by surrounding them with

```
<!--
```

and

```
-->
```

IMO you could also set up the XSL so that it got its filter information from a specific item rather than hardcoding the conditions, but perhaps better to see if this can do the job for you first.